# No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.fileZipOperation() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

My Seedjob creates a job, which needs to fulfill some fileOperation tasks - so I am using the fileOperations plugin, which are doing what they should, except this:
    fileZipOperation('target/unpacked')

> I am getting this exception, when my seed job in Jenkins runs (it failes then):

**No signature of method:**
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.fileZipOperation() is
applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

> When I configure a job 'by hand' and set up fileZipOperation,

it needs one string parameter `folderPath` - and it works. Zip is created just fine.
I even looked into the sourceCodes in GitHub, but I can't see the problem. Any help - thank you in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Dynamic DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL) to configure file operations:

```
job('example') {
  steps {
    fileOperationsBuilder {
      fileOperations {
        fileZipOperation {
          folderPath('test')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```